# youtube ?rel=0 not working on iOS

Tags: youtube-api

the youtube ?rel=0 is not working on iOS 6, e.g. at the end of video related videos are being shown. any workaround? (cant use embed...must be url)

guess i should have added, it works fine in jwplayer but only on pre-iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

Use this format http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoId?&rel=0 If you use this link in an embedded iframe for a site it will play the video on the Safari browser rather then using the YouTube iOS App.

Comment: 1) on web, got this error: Playlist could not be loaded due to crossdomain policy restrictions. 2. on iOS 6...doesn't work

Comment: 1. You're probably missing the crossdomain.xml file, which is restricting the video from playing. It should help if you're using a module to play the video. 2. It will not work because it's not formatted to play a playlist, just a single video. Here you will find the [correct embed code to use on the playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Selecting_Content_to_Play).